# Estimiating Bruce's Beers Choice, given Sam's Soft drink choice, both depending only on the Weather

Tags: bayesian, estimation, conditional-probability, sample, discrete-data

Consider a couple of blokes, Bruce and Sam.

Sam is a Software engineer who likes softdrinks (Sam's Softdrinks
come from a set $\mathbf{s}=\{s_{1},...,s_{n_{s}}\}$. $n_{s}$ is
reasonably small, just like 30ish types of softdrink -- Sam is a conosure).

Sam knows that he likes different drinks depending on the weather
(the weather is a complicated discrete variable, from a set $\mathbf{c}=\{c_{1},...,c_{n_{3}}\}$
$n_{c}$ is extremely large $n_{c}\approx10^{70}$, it is iself made
up of many independent factors -- say 70 factors than can take 10
values each).

If if was really hot, he'd like a refreshing lemon squash. If it was
overcast until noon, he want something caffeinated like coke.

Sam spent a long time making drink dispensing machine, that took into
account a pile of sensors, and data about him, to determine what drink
he would like. He doesn't want it to be entirely deterministic, so
it outputs a probability of choosing each drink, then gives him one
randomly, according to that.

So the machine outputs: $P(s_{i}\mid c_{k})$ -- the probability of
each drink ($s_{i}$), given today's weather ($c_{k}$), and Sam is
happy, cos he doensn't really like making decisions.

Sam's neighbor Bruce, is a builder -- but *also* a massive nerd.
Bruce likes beer (Bruce's beers come from a set: $\mathbf{b}=\{b_{1},\,...,b_{n_{b}}\}$,
Bruce has less beers than Sam has soft drinks (not that it should
matter for this question)).

Bruce loved the idea of Sam's machine, so he built one of his own.
He got a parts list from Sam, and so built a machine with all the
same sensors.

But he wired it up differently -- according to his own preferences.
The distribution is still determined only by the weather, and it still has a random element.

So this machine outputs $P(b_{j}|c_{k})$, and randomly select Bruce
a beer.

Each day, Sam and Bruce sit on their verandas, with their drinks.

Oneday Sam find himself wondering: What *is* the logic of Bruce's
machine? Sam decide he want to try and work out what the probabilities
$P(b_{j}|c_{k})$ being displayed on Bruce's machine before it drops
a drink -- by looking at the output of his own machine. Sam doesn't
want to try and dig into raw outputs of his sensors to try and capture
$c_{k}$ directly -- plus he is pretty sure Bruce generally follows
roughly similar logic to him -- it seems on the humid days Sam tends
to like a Lemon Squash, Bruce generally seems to drink a Golden Lager
-- there is no simple relationship but in general Sam and Bruce both
want the same kinda things a lot of the time, for the same weather.

Sam start writing down each day what drink Bruce came out holding,
next to the probabilities output by his machine; he does this for
many months.

Not enough time to see the full range of weathers ($\mathbf{c}$)
but a subset, that should be useful.

**So the goal is: use $P(s_{i}|c_{k})$ to estimate $P(b_{j}|c_{k})$.**,
based on the samples Sam have taken over past many months.

---

What I think Sam is actually going to be able to find is, to write it formally:

$$
P(B=b_{j}|C=c_{k}\cap\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{i=n_{s}}Q_{i}=P(S=s_{i}\mid C=c_{k})\right))
$$

defining a new random variable $Q_{i}=P(S=s_{i}\mid C=c_{k})$, i.e. the random variable is itself the probability output by Sam's machine for each of Sam's drinks.

---

<sub>This problem is a recasting of a more abstract problem I have been having about how I can use a known model $P(s_i|c_k)$, to help better estimate an unknown distribution $P(b_j|c_k)$ that is expected to be very similar, but is not over the same observed variables. And which I have a finite, but largish number of observations allowing my to correlate the output of the known model, to observed output of the other conditional distribution</sub>

Comment: My concern here is that the number of discrete weather conditions is too large and c(k) may never repeat. Additionally, treating weather conditions as discrete doesn't make it clear that two very similar conditions are "close" to each other. Instead, could you consider the weather as a set of n variables that are normally (or uniformly or whatever) distributed?

Comment: @barrycarter the number of weather conditions *is* too large, and doesn't carry information about closeness. Which is part of the motivation for using $P(s_i \mid c_k)$ as I guess a "proxy" for the weather.The vector of all probilities of sam's soft drinks is much much smaller than the number of possible weathers and captures most of the meaningful patterns. And it does have a measure of closeness.